# Python counting characters of each string in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, text, analysis

this is my first post and I'm just starting out in Python programming.

So, for an assignment I have to analyze a text, by stating the number of words it contains and then by stating how many words have n characters.

This is what I have come up with, but my n for the number of characters is limited..and there must be a more elegant way to do this.

I want the output to be something like:

"The text contains:

3 words with 4 characters

n words with n characters"

I know "how" to do it theoretically, but don't know how to use code to do it.

1. `sort d[i]` by `len(d[i])`

2.store the words with same length in a variable

```
text = input("Type your text: ") 
words = text.split()
number_of_words = len(words)

print("Result:\nthe text contains", number_of_words, "words") 

d = {}
i = 0

for words in text.split():
    d[i] = words
    i += 1

n = 0
p = 0
q = 0

for i in d:
    if len(d[i]) == 1:
       n += 1
    elif len(d[i]) == 2:
       p += 1
    elif len(d[i]) == 3:
       q += 1

print(n, "words with 1 character")
print(p, "words with 2 characters")
print(q, "words with 3 characters")
```

Comment: What do you mean about *counting characters of each string in a dictionary* ? An example input and output?

Comment: Input is the text. Output for example is: "The text contains n words with x characters and n words with y characters"

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to python but as per your requirement this may work.

```
 text = raw_input("Type your text: ") 
 words = text.split()
 print words
 for i in words:
     print 'string=',i , ', length=',len(i)
```

Taking input from user and splitting it by spaces then loop over the list `words` and use len function to get the string length instead of counting them individually

Answer (score 0):

Consider the built-in python function `sort()` (See: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)).

You probably want to use a list instead of a dictionary for `d`, because the key is simply an int index.

```
d = text.split()
d.sort(key=len(d[i]))

charcount = 1
prev_i = 0
for i in range(len(d)):
    if len(d[i]) > len(d[i-1]):
        print i-prev_i, "words with %d characters" % charcount
        prev_i = i
        charcount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :)

```
text = raw_input("Type your text: ")
words = text.split()


print ("Result:\nthe text contains" + str(len(words)) + "words")

# Using a list instead of a dictionary
d = []

# Loop over the list, word by word
for i in words:
        # Exception if full stop found. Probably should filter out other characters as well to be safe. (cause user input)
    if i.find('.')!=-1:
        # Remove fullstops
        q = i.replace(".", "")
        # Add word to the end of our list
        d.append(q)
    else:
        # If no punctuation encountered, just add the word
        d.append(i)

# test out
print d

# The rest seems legit enough
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to use list comprehensions and built-in list methods:

```
text = raw_input('type:' )
type:adam sam jessica mike
lens = [len(w) for w in text.split()]
print [lens.count(i) for i in range(10)]

[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```